# ¿ Como añadir un texto a los precios de los productos de WooCommerce dependiendo el usuario?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, users-roles

Quiero cambiar el texto que tiene el precio de los productos dependiendo del rol del usuario.
En el sitio web hay 12 roles de usuario diferente:
**Administrador, Editor, Autor, Colaborador, Suscriptor, Cliente, Cliente Minorista, Cliente Mayorista, Gestor de la tienda, Wholesale Customer y 2 roles de SEO**.
Actualmente y gracias al usuario @OCHOA creo una función desde la cual, el texto del precio para el usuario con rol `Wholesale Customer` es P.V.M ( precio para mayorista ) y para el rol de `Cliente`, el precio debe ser P.V.P. (precio venta al publico).

Ahora, cuando llegamos a la web por primera vez,  P.V.P. acompaña al precio de los productos, ya que el usuario por defecto es cliente. gracias la siguiente función:

```
function my_get_current_user_roles() {
  if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
      return $roles; // This will returns an array
  } else {
      return  array();
  }
}

function custom_price_message( $price ) { 
  global $post; 
  $product_id = $post->ID; 
  $roles = my_get_current_user_roles();
  $textafter = "";
  if(!empty($roles)) { 
      if (in_array("wholesale_customer", $roles)) {
          $textafter = ''; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
      if (in_array("customer", $roles)) {
          $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
  }
  else{
      $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; // Or whatever you want
  }
  return $price . '' . $textafter . ''; //class textafter para el  
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message');
```

El problema es que el resto de roles (Administrador, Editor, Autor, Colaborador, Suscriptor, Cliente Minorista, Cliente Mayorista, Gestor de la tienda, y 2 roles de SEO ) no les muestra ningún texto añadido al precio.

La necesidad es que todos los roles reciban el texto P.V.P. junto al precio, excepto en los roles Wholesale Customer y  Cliente Mayorista
He tratado de hacer un condicional para distinguir los usuarios, pero no encuentro la idea para hacerlo.
He tratado de añadirlos al segundo array, pero no se como hacerlo y me da error:

```
function custom_price_message( $price ) { 
  global $post; 
  $product_id = $post->ID; 
  $roles = my_get_current_user_roles();
  $textafter = "";
  if(!empty($roles)) { 
      if (in_array("wholesale_customer", $roles)) {
          $textafter = ''; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
      if (in_array("customer","administrator",  $roles)) {
          $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
  }
  else{
      $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; // Or whatever you want
  }
  return $price . '' . $textafter . ''; //class textafter para el  
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message');
```

¿ Como debo hacer el condicional para que todos los roles excepto **Wholesale Customer y  Cliente Mayorista** muestren el texto P.V.P.

Los cambios en tu código PHP se han revertido debido a un error en la línea 53 del archivo wp-content/themes//functions.php. Por favor, arréglalo y trata de guardar de nuevo.

```
Uncaught TypeError: in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, string given in wp-content/themes/functions.php:53
Stack trace:
#0 wp-content/themes/functions.php(53): in_array('customer', 'administrator', Array)
#1 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): custom_price_message('<span class="wo...')
#2 wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters('<span class="wo...', Array)
#3 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(1872): apply_filters('woocommerce_get...', '<span class="wo...', Object(WC_Product_Simple))
#4 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/price.php(25): WC_Product->get_price_html()
#5 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(345): include('/homepages/20/d...')
#6 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php(1390): wc_get_template('loop/price.php')
#7 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): woocommerce_template_loop_price('')
#8 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#9 wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#10 wp-content/themes/flatsome/woocommerce/content-product.php(78): do_action('woocommerce_aft...')
#11 wp-includes/template.php(785): require('/homepages/20/d...')
#12 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(284): load_template('/homepages/20/d...', false)
#13 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-products.php(660): wc_get_template_part('content', 'product')
#14 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-products.php(100): WC_Shortcode_Products->product_loop()
#15 wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php(283): WC_Shortcode_Products->get_content()
#16 wp-includes/shortcodes.php(355): WC_Shortcodes::products(Array, '', 'products')
#17 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array)
#18 wp-includes/shortcodes.php(227): preg_replace_callback('/\\[(\\[?)(produc...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '<div class="blo...')
#19 wp-content/themes/flatsome/inc/post-types/post-type-ux-blocks.php(158): do_shortcode('<div class="blo...')
#20 wp-includes/shortcodes.php(355): block_shortcode(Array, '', 'block')
#21 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array)
#22 wp-includes/shortcodes.php(227): preg_replace_callback('/\\[(\\[?)(ux_sli...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '\n[ux_slider tim...')
#23 wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): do_shortcode('\n[ux_slider tim...')
#24 wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters('\n[ux_slider tim...', Array)
#25 wp-includes/post-template.php(255): apply_filters('the_content', '<!-- wp:flatsom...')
#26 wp-content/themes/flatsome/page-blank.php(17): the_content()
#27 wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/homepages/20/d...')
#28 wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/homepages/20/d...')
#29 index.php(17): require('/homepages/20/d...')
#30 {main}
  thrown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pues he conseguido hacerlo.
Se obtiene el rol de usuario con `wp_get_current_user()`
y con una función y el filtro de WooCommerce `woocommerce_get_price_html` mostramos el texto necesario

```
function my_get_current_user_roles() {
  if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
      return $roles; // This will returns an array
  } else {
      return  array();
  }
}

function mostrar_mensaje( $price ) { 
  global $post; 
  $product_id = $post->ID; 
  $roles = my_get_current_user_roles();
  $textafter = "";
  if(!empty($roles)) { 
      if (in_array("wholesale_customer", $roles)) {
          $textafter = ''; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
      if (in_array("customer", $roles)  or in_array("administrator",$roles)) {
          $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
  }
  else{
      $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; 
  }
  return $price . '' . $textafter . ''; //class textafter para el  
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'mostrar_mensaje');
```

Answer (score 1):

La funcion [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) recibe como primer parametro, que cosa tiene que buscar, y como segundo parametro el array donde buscar...

Pero vos, le estas mandando como array, otra cosa a buscar...

```
if (in_array("customer","administrator",  $roles))
```

Obviamente, esto no funciona y tira un error.. Y si probamos con un or???

```
if (in_array("customer",$roles) or in_array("administrator",$roles))
```

Comment: Gracias por tu idea @gbianchi. Por supuesto eso funciona. Mi pregunta es si no podría hacerse de otro modo, ya que estaria obligado a poner todos los roles en el if. ¿ Eso es lo más apropiado ? ¿ No se puede hacer lo contrario ? Quiero decir, los roles **Wholesale Customer y Cliente Mayorista** llevan un texto y el resto de roles llevan otro texto. ¿Como hacer : Si el rol es Wholesale Customer o Cliente Mayorista, el texto sea P.V.M. - De lo contrario, el texto sea P.V.P . Estoy tratando de idear la logica asi, pero no se como plasmarla en el código, ¿que te parece ?

Comment: La logica que planteas, es exactamente igual... si es uno de esos roles, escribis un texto.. y  si no, en el else, que son todos los otros roles, escribis otro... @Estudiante